# How to find optimal number of clusters with Scikit-Learn and Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm learning clustering with `Python`s `scikit-learn` lib but I cant find a way to find the optimal number of clusters. I have tried to make a list of numbers of clusters and to pass it in `for loop`, and to see `elbow` but I want to find better solution. This way works only if i do it for the `range(1,11)` after that line becomes very smooth and I cant see the `elbow`.
I have tried `silhouette_score` but I get very low values, sometimes negative.

Also, Im using text data, i wrote a couple of sentences that can be *(let say) grouped, i have sentences about house/home, about studying, parties, food....

Is there a chance that Im getting low values of `silhouette_score` because Im using text data, also do I need to scale the data after `cv.fit_transform(doc)`?

Is there any better way, maybe some function that will return the `integer` value of the optimal number of clusters? For example 1,2,3,4....n

This is the code that I wrote:

```
import sklearn.metrics as sm

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer, TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.preprocessing import scale
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans, SpectralClustering, MiniBatchKMeans
from sklearn.metrics import silhouette_samples, silhouette_score

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

doc = ['this is very good show' , 'i had a great time on my school trip', 'such a boring movie', 'Springbreak was amazing', 'You are wrong', 'let s go to the beach', 'how can we do this',
     'i love this product', 'this is an amazing item', 'this food is delicious', 'I had a great time last night', 'thats right', ' lets go to the party', 'we were at the party last night', 
     'this is my favourite restaurant, I love their food, its so good','i love healty food', 'skiing is the best sport', 'what is this', 'this product has a lot of bugs', "i'm on the road again", 
     'I love basketball, its very dynamic' , 'its a shame that you missed the trip, it was amazing', 'Party last night was so boring', 'lets go on road trip', 'this is my home, im living there for 26 years',
     'such a nice song' , 'this is the best movie ever', 'hawaii is the best place for trip','how that happened','This is my favourite band', 'true love', 'party was great','home sweet home',
     'I cant believe that you did that', 'Why are you doing that, I do not get it', 'this is tasty', 'this song is amazing', 'this food is tasty', 'lets go to the cinema', 'lets get together at my house',
     'I need to study for the test', 'I cant go out this weekend', 'I had a great time last night', 'I went out last night and it was amazing', 'you are beautiful', 'we crashed the party',
     'this is the best song i have ever heard', 'i love listening to music', 'music is my life', 'this song is terrible', 'how was your hollyday', 'i do not understand you, I have told you that last night',
      'I know whats best for you', 'I m on collage now', 'this is my favourite subject', 'math is fun', 'i love to study maths', 'programming is my live', 'i need to study, my final exam is tomorrow',
      'i m cooming home', 'i need to clean my house', 'what do you thing about last night', 'lets go out, my house is a mess', 'Im staying at home tonight', 'love is such a beautiful word',
      'i want to buy new house for me and my family', 'im will be home in a couple of hours', 'im working on a science project', 'working is hard and i need to work', 'you need to find a job',
       'this is bad, and we cant do anything about that', 'real estate market is growing', 'im selling my appartment', 'i live at the appartment above', 'i m into real estate', 'prices are going down',
       'i m building house of cards', 'I feel so tired, i was studying all nigh long', 'i was playing piano for more than 10 years and I was pretty good at it','I have never done that in my life',
       'i will buy this product in a couple of days', 'i m buying new phone next month', 'my home is near by', 'i m living in my home', 'i live in my parents house', 'i m living in my appartment',
       'my phone is very slow', 'do you know password for wifi', 'wifi is short for wireless network', 'you are so funny', 'my neighbours are horrible', 'such a nice phone, im glad to have it',
       'last time we went into that club and it was so boring', 'if I were you, i would never said that', 'you done very good work, your boss is very proud of you', 'Overall, I like this place a lot',
       'I was spending money on wrong things', 'whats the price for this item', 'where can I buy it', 'is it for sale', 'This hole in the wall has great Mexican street tacos, and friendly staff'
       'The movie showed a lot of Florida at it s best, made it look very appealing', 'This short film certainly pulls no punches', 'This is the kind of money that is wasted properly',
       'Not only did it only confirm that the film would be unfunny and generic, but it also managed to give away the ENTIRE movie', 'But it s just not funny','you have already done that',
       'I especially liked the non-cliche choices with the parents', 'it was well-paced and suited its relatively short run time']


cv = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer = 'word', max_features = 4000, lowercase=True, preprocessor=None, tokenizer=None, stop_words = 'english')  
x = cv.fit_transform(doc)

my_list = []
for i in range(1,10):

    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = i, init = 'k-means++', random_state = 0)
    kmeans.fit(x)
    my_list.append(kmeans.inertia_)
    silhouette_avg = silhouette_score(x, cluster_labels)
    print(silhouette_avg)

plt.plot(range(1,10),my_list)
plt.show()
```

Comment: there is many methods try to search for The “Elbow” Method, The Silhouette Method ...

Comment: I have tried elbow method and I have tried silhouette method. With silhouette method i get scores of 0.002-0,05 and thats very low, also sometimes I get negative values. Is that because Im using text data?
Do I need to scale my `x` value after I do `cv.fit_transform(doc)`?

Comment: Have you considered trying MeanShift clustering of Affinity Propagation? Neither requires predetermining the number of clusters. See https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html

Comment: I did , i get silhouette  score around 6, and thats also very low

Comment: Try this: https://blog.cambridgespark.com/how-to-determine-the-optimal-number-of-clusters-for-k-means-clustering-14f27070048f

Answer (score 0):

Finding the optimal number of cluster is, in general, an hard problem as there isn't a unique solution to it and that problem is not deterministic (especially for text data). Furthermore, the optimal solution of a clustering problem is a local optimum that optimize a given measure behind the model you use, and it exists a large number of [clustering models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis).

Therefore, a baseline that automatically learn the "right" number of clusters for text data is the so called Hierarchical Dirichlet Process (HDP), which generalized the Latent Dirichlet Allocation ([LDA](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.LatentDirichletAllocation.html)) model.

You can find examples and use cases of the HDP in the [gensim library](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/hdpmodel.html#gensim.models.hdpmodel.HdpModel).